# Regular expression to match words with word boundary in a sentence using Perl?

Tags: perl

Is their a way to match a word in the following sentence with word boundary and should match the words with dash, braket, comma, fullstop etc. at the right or left of the word.

Eg:

```
 $str = "The quick brown fox (jump) over the lazy dog yes jumped, fox is quick jump, and jump-up and jump.";
```

how can i match the 4 occurance of the word 'jump' in the sample sentence using perl regular expression?

NOTE: i dont want to match the word 'jumped'.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @words = $str =~ m{\bjump\b}g;
print "@words\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

> A word boundary ("\b") is a spot between two characters that has a
>   "\w" on one side of it and a "\W" on the other side of it (in either
>   order), counting the imaginary characters off the beginning and end of
>   the string as matching a "\W".

-- [perldoc perlre > Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions)

```
foreach($str=~/\b(jump)\b/g){
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "$_\n" for $str =~ /\bjump\b/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @arr = $string =~ m{\bjump\b}g;
print "@arr\n";
```